# lost with mySQL INNER Join query

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Ok I have this query I am playing with. Which is working to a point but still not getting the exact results I'd like.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.friendID, b.isactive, c.*
            FROM memb_baseInfo a INNER JOIN memb_friends b ON
            a.mID = b.mID
            INNER JOIN memb_baseInfo c ON
            b.friendID = c.mID
            WHERE b.`isactive` = 0 OR b.`isactive` = 1
            AND a.mID = '21'
```

$mid being the dynamic variable.

What i want to do is find on the table memb_friends the mID or friendID that match the dynamic $mid given. From that get information from the another table. memb_baseInfo. Where the mID is the foreign key of sorts. Both tables have mID as the matching variable. but in memb_friends friendID and mID are essentially one in the same as far as the memb_baseInfo table goes. My dummy data is basically my mID and 5 fake ones, 2 of which are nothing to do with me currently, and 3 which have made a friendship with me. My problem is this is only gathering information where my mID (21) has friendID but if someone has friended me and there number is the mID in the friend table then I dont get there information. Ive been trying to figure out how to do it both ways but am failing. Hopefully I made sense, anyone able to help>?

Comment: At first look, I can say you should take `b.`isactive` = 0 OR b.`isactive` = 1 ` in bracket like `(b.`isactive` = 0 OR b.`isactive` = 1)`. If it does not help, i look at further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look for the friends of 21, right? Use this: (Not tested)

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
  FROM memb_baseInfo a
 WHERE a.mID IN (
  SELECT b.friendID FROM memb_baseInfo a INNER JOIN memb_friends b ON a.mID = b.mID
   WHERE (b.`isactive` = 0 OR b.`isactive` = 1)
     AND a.mID = '21')
```

Answer (score 0):

After continuing to play around with it while waiting for answer I actually came up with

```
SELECT * FROM memb_friends a 
INNER JOIN memb_baseInfo b ON a.friendID = b.mID OR a.mID = b.mID
WHERE a.isactive = 1 AND b.mID NOT IN(".$mid.") AND (a.mID = '".$mid."' OR a.friendID = '".$mid."')
```

where $mid would be 21 as given in the original query above. This will get me all the connections I have and result in all the information I currently require from my original question.